# Please help me understand why in this JavaScript function the onclick on this div always refers to the last added div

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, ecmascript-6

I have a simple JavaSciript function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ECMAScript</title>
    <style>
      #box {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }
      #box > div {
        height: 5em;
        width: 5em;
        background-color: purple;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Let</h1>
    <div id="box"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var div;
      var box = document.getElementById("box");

      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.onclick = function () {
          alert("This is box # " + i);
        };
        box.appendChild(div);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you copy paste this code in a text editor and save it as .html, a simple webpage with 5 purple boxes show up. When I click on any box I get the message:

> This is box# 5

I am not sure why.

I understand the difference between let and diff and changing the **var i** to **let i** solves the issue.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

to this line

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

I would love to understand why this happens.

Comment: scope ... of var = function, of let = block

Comment: You could just define `div` inside the loop, since you don't seem to be using it outside of the loop anyway.

Comment: @Geshode as long as it's a block scoped variable that would work just as well